# Google map infowindow maxWidth issues

Tags: google-maps

USing version 3, the maxWidth doesnt seem to work if it's less than 200

Answer (score 3):

Here's a [google group discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_thread/thread/0e77b0f16e53ae38#). It includes examples of how to [style](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infowindow_custom/infowindow-custom.html) [your](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/smartinfowindow/smartinfowindow.html) [own](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.0/examples/infobox-basic.html) infowindow. I haven't read up on it yet.

Answer (score 0):

> this.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
>               maxWidth: 300,
>               content: "..."
>           });

maxWidth should be greater than 250

Maximum width of the infowindow, regardless of content's width. This value is only considered if it is set before a call to open. To change the maximum width when changing content, call close, setOptions, and then open.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, adding a div element inside the infoWindow and set the width by css.

Ex.:

```
this.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
{ 
    maxWidth: 300, 
    content: "<div class='div-info'>....</div>" 
});
```

Css Definition:

```
.div-info { 
    max-width: 300px; 
}
```